# Netifaces package download throwing errors

Tags: python, python-netifaces

I am trying to install netifaces

This is the error i recieve.

Collecting netifaces
Using cached netifaces-0.11.0.tar.gz (30 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
Building wheel for netifaces (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for netifaces (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
C:\Users\KRAMESH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qxb18xih\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
**  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
Failed to build netifaces
ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**

What can be done?

I install Visual BuildTools but i am clueless about it